# Drag function in Blocks is Gone

Tags: blocks

In one of my Drupal installations I suddenly noticed I can no longer drag and sort the order of my blocks. The image shows on the left the admin with now drag handles and a screenshot of another admin with the handles.

[image: screenshot]

What could have happened? I think its AJAX/JavaScript related.

Comment: Which theme is being used in the first screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely js related, most likely a conflict/error from something in the theme or a contributed module. If you switch to a core theme, are the blocks draggable? If not, it's probably a module (or a script coming from somewhere else, like a block).

If you need to change block position ASAP, you can temporarily disable your browser's javascript, which should then cause the weight positioning drop-downs to appear, which you can use to adjust the order.

Comment: In order to find out if this is the problem, you should evaluate the javascript-errors presented by the browser. In Firefox you can do this with the [firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/).